# Chain calls of Observable not working with pipe, map

Tags: angular, dictionary, post, pipe, observable

I have few functions here which on successful response keep adding some useful data to the response received and further send it as a parameter to another HTTP call and finally returns everything to the parent function. After the first call, I am not able to get the data.

```
getBulkDataForSelectedids(inputIDs) {          //an array of objects with key as "etype" and corresponding ids
    if (inputIDs !== null && inputIDs.length > 0) {
      let observableArray: any = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < inputIDs.length; i++) {
        const ids = inputIDs[i]["IDs"];
        const entityType = inputIDs[i]["Type"];
        ids.forEach((id) => {
          observableArray.push(this.getbulkInfoBulkArrayIdURL(entityType, id));
        });
      }
      observableForkJoin(observableArray).subscribe(
        (response: any) => {
          console.log(response);            //wait for all response
        },
        (error: any) => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
    }
  }

  getbulkInfoBulkArrayIdURL(etype, guid) {
    return this.service
      .getCall(                     // simple HTTP get call in the service
        "/api/entities/" +
          etype +
          "/" +
          id
      )
      .pipe(
        map((response: object) => {
          const bulkInfoBulkArrayIdURL = response["bulkInfoBulkArrayIdURL"];
          return this.getsampleCount(bulkInfoBulkArrayIdURL, response);
        }),
        catchError((err) => {
          return of(null);
        })
      );
  }

  getsampleCount(url, bulkInfoResponse) {
    return this.service.getCall(url).pipe(      // simple HTTP get call in the service
      flatMap((response) => {
        let sampleCount = response["recordCount"];
        return this.getBulkArrayData(url, sampleCount, bulkInfoResponse);
      }),
      catchError((err) => {
        return of(null);
      })
    );
  }

  getBulkArrayData(url, sampleCount, bulkInfoResponse) {
    return this.service
      .getCall(url + sampleCount)     // simple HTTP get call in the service
      .pipe(
        map((response: object) => {
          return this.ConvertBulkArray(response, bulkInfoResponse);
        }),
        catchError((err) => {
          return of(null);
        })
      );
  }

  ConvertBulkArray(response: object, bulkInfoResponse) {
      // uses this two parameters and create output
    const output = {
      property1 : object,
    };
    
    return output;
  }
```

In the `getbulkInfoBulkArrayIdURL` method I successfully get the output from the line `const bulkInfoBulkArrayIdURL = response["bulkInfoBulkArrayIdURL"];` but then the call to `return this.getsampleCount(bulkInfoBulkArrayIdURL, response);` does not return anything. Is this the best way to achieve chaining or I am missing something? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks a bit messy, but I think the problem here is that in your `getBulkArrayData` method you pipe a `map` on the observable. This creates a second order observable, which you probably do not want in this case. If you change `map` to `switchMap`, it will also subscribe when it receives a value.

Comment: Yes, it was a problem with the map only. I used concatMap and it worked. Thanks for the help.